# Add OneNote to Document Library Templates?

Tags: library, document-template, onenote

I am trying to add a blank One Note document to the document web part so when a user hits the "+ NEW" button they have an option to create a new word, excel, power point or one note document, as shown below:

[image]

I have no idea how to add a new document type to this template, I went into library settings but couldn't figure it out. It seems like a simple solution but I'm stuck.

I appreciate any help!

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can add a new document type into the document library easily through the following steps:

- Create a New Site content type by going to Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Site Content Types under Galleries. Use the Parent Content Type **Document** from **Document Content Types** Group.
- Name the content Type something like "OneNote Document".
- Go to the Advanced Settings of the newly created content type, add a new OneNote Document template.
- Next, Go to your document library settings page, and go to Advanced Settings.
- Here, set **Allow Management of Content Types** to **Yes** and click Ok.
- Next, Add the Newly created Content Type to the Library.

You should now be able to see the new document type in the New Document dropdown. Visit [here](http://www.sharepoint.inf4web.com/1313/sharepoint-2013-how-to-add-additional-document-types-to-a-document-library/) for more details.

Comment: This answer has just made some assumptions based on other Office formats. But OneNote works differently. It is actually stored as a Folder and not Document type. And there is not a single document template for OneNote, which could be uploaded (like e.g. dotx for Word).
Nevertheless, I have tried these steps and just used file called "New Section 1.one" as template, which I have found in corresponding OneNote folder (from an existing DocLib) - it did not work out as I expected anyway. Any ideas how it could be achieved with OneNote? I found more questions than real answers in the Internet...

Comment: It does also not work with .onepkg file, which is a single packaged export file for notebooks. This answer from Microsoft does not indicate that it is feasible with OneNote: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/creating-a-onenote-document-template-in-sharepoint/52c563c7-062c-45b8-8f77-4f04f9f65c54